# ansible does not expand var in ver 2.9, it works in 2.8

Tags: ansible

We are using this in a ansible playbook, and it works in ansible 2.8.3, but in 2.9.6, the `{{env}}` in the archive path string is not expanded, is it a bug, or am I doing something wrong ?

```
 - name: Archive images
    shell: "/usr/bin/docker save bbs-docker-virtual.artifactory.t3t.dk/{{ item.name }}:{{ item.tag }} | /bin/gzip -c > {{ item.archive }}"
    args:
      executable: /bin/bash
    when: archive_images is defined and archive_images and item.archive != ''
    with_items:
      - name:    "bbs.nmr"
        archive: "{{ 'images/{{env}}/bbs.nmr.tar.gz' if nmr_image_id != 'SKIP' else '' }}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression delimiter, `{{ ... }}`, inside another expression delimiter seems buggy, to be honest.

You can always use the [concatenation operator](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#other-operators), `~`, in jinja for those:

```yaml
archive: "{{ 'images/' ~ env ~ '/bbs.nmr.tar.gz' if nmr_image_id != 'SKIP' else '' }}"
```